# How can I wrap lines automatically and manually at the same time?

Tags: tables

To make table modification more easy, I normally use m{...} as columns' type. This is very convenient when I write long sentences.

But sometimes I need wrap lines before this line is filled to help understanding.

For example, I write a technical term, and then I want to wrap lines to add a note under the term.

I have tried `\makecell` and `\newline` to wrap lines.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{m{2cm}<{\centering}|m{2cm}}\hline
        \makecell[c]{A\\(note)} & this is a very loooooooooooooooog sentence\\\hline
        A\newline(note) & this is a very loooooooooooooooog sentence\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The `\makecell` method makes **A** and **(note)** both horizontal center, but they as a whole are not vertical center.

The `\newline` method makes the whole vertical center, but **A** is somehow not horizontal center.

Comment: `m{2cm}<{\centering}` is pretty weird, it adds `\centering` at the end of the entry, so if you don't leave a blank line the last paragraph (only) will be centered and all earlier paragraphs will be justifiesd. `>{\centering}m{2cm}` would be more normal as it adds `\centering` before the text not after it  (and you could then use `\\ ` to force a line break as well.

Comment: Thank you, I have never noticed that. You have solved me a potential problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother.

I find that just add a blank line will fix it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}m{2cm}|m{2cm}}\hline
        A

        (note) & this is a very loooooooooooooooog sentence\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which means that a `\par` would also work instead of the blank line.

Comment: Yes, that makes the code look better.

Comment: the main change here is putting `\centering`  before A  (so it gets centered)  as noted in comments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I find something bad if I use `>{\centering}m{}` at the last column (more than one column) then the \\ will be recognized as `\par` and the code will go wrong.

Comment: use \centering\arraybackslash so that  `\\ ` keeps its tabular meanimg or use `\tabularnewline` to end the row, that's why I said you could use `\\ ` after A to get a newline in your first column @oneplus

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks.